# A single SQL query to deal with more than one one-to-many relationship and output the results once only

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

I have 3 database tables that have between them 2 totally separate one-to-many relationships and I'm having great difficulty in writing a single SQL query to output a single record for each relevant piece of information.

Maybe, in the end, as the 2 relationships are separate it means I'll need to write 2 separate connections and SQL queries but I thought I'd ask anyway in the vain hope that someone out there has had and solved a similar issue (and in solving this I could then apply the same principle to other separate one-to-many relationships that occur throughout the database and could 'ideally' create one large query rather than even more separate connections/queries).

The query I have so far is:

```
SELECT C.court_id, court_email_desc, court_email_addr, court_opening_type_desc, court_opening_desc
FROM court C
JOIN court_email CE ON C.court_id = CE.court_id
JOIN court_opening CO ON C.court_id = CO.court_id
JOIN court_opening_type COT ON CO.court_opening_type_id = COT.court_opening_type_id
WHERE C.court_id = '" + court_id_no + "'
ORDER BY C.court_id
```

which outputs something along the lines of:

Enquiries : enquiries@enquiries.email
Court building open : 8.30 am

Bailiffs : bailiffs@bailiffs.email
Court building open : 8.30 am

Hearings : hearings@hearings.email
Court building open : 8.30 am

Filing e-documents : ccmcce-filing@filing.email
Court building open : 8.30 am

Public Enquiries Email : ccmcccustomerenquiries@pubenq.email
Court building open : 8.30 am

Enquiries : enquiries@enquiries.email
Court building closed : 5.00 pm

Bailiffs : bailiffs@bailiffs.email
Court building closed : 5.00 pm

etc.... (**NB:** the email addresses are repeated 4 times, once for each type of opening desc)

The **desired output** would be something like this:

Enquiries : enquiries@enquiries.email
Bailiffs : bailiffs@bailiffs.email
Hearings : hearings@hearings.email
Filing e-documents : ccmcce-filing@filing.email
Public Enquiries Email : ccmcccustomerenquiries@pubenq.email

Court building open : 8.30 am
Court building closed : 5.00 pm
Telephone Enquiries from : 9.00am
Telephone Enquiries until : 5.00pm

Is there a way I can cleverly nest the query to output each email address and opening type/time only once for whichever court I choose to display? Would this even be possible in the SQL query or would the clever bit come in the C# when I output the results?

My C# code currently stands as below:

```
myDataReader3 = myCommand3.ExecuteReader();

        if (myDataReader3.HasRows) {

            string last_id = string.Empty;
            string last_id2 = string.Empty;

            while (myDataReader3.Read()) {

                string court_id = myDataReader3["court_id"].ToString();
                string court_email_desc = myDataReader3["court_email_desc"].ToString();
                string court_email_addr = myDataReader3["court_email_addr"].ToString();
                string court_opening = myDataReader3["court_opening_desc"].ToString();
                string court_opening_type = myDataReader3["court_opening_type_desc"].ToString();

                if (last_id != court_id) {

                    Response.Write("<br><strong>Email address</strong><br>" + court_email_desc + ": " + court_email_addr + "<br>");

                } else {

                    Response.Write(court_email_desc + ": " + court_email_addr + "<br>");

                }

                last_id = court_id;

                if (last_id2 != court_id) {

                    Response.Write("<br><strong>Opening times</strong><br>" + court_opening_type + ": " + court_opening + "<br>");

                } else {

                    Response.Write(court_opening_type + ": " + court_opening + "<br>");

                }

                last_id2 = court_id;

            }

        }
```

Thanks in advance for your time and any help that comes my way.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to add the `row_number() over()` to your SQL query and then apply a `CASE` statement:

```
select court_id,
  court_email_desc,
  case when rn=1 then court_email_addr else '' end court_email_addr,
  court_opening_type_desc,
  court_opening_desc
from
(
  SELECT C.court_id, 
    court_email_desc, 
    court_email_addr, 
    court_opening_type_desc, 
    court_opening_desc,
    row_number() over(partition by c.court_id order by c.court_id) rn
  FROM court C
  JOIN court_email CE 
    ON C.court_id = CE.court_id
  JOIN court_opening CO 
    ON C.court_id = CO.court_id
  JOIN court_opening_type COT 
    ON CO.court_opening_type_id = COT.court_opening_type_id
  WHERE C.court_id = '" + court_id_no + "'
) src
order by court_id
```

What this is doing is adding a `row_number()` to original query and by `court_id`. Then you apply a `CASE` statement to the fields you are returning checking if the `row_number` is equal to 1. If it is then you will display the value of the column. If not, then it will show an empty string.

Edit #1: If you only want the `Open` and `closed` values to appear once, you can also `PIVOT` the data similar to this:

```
SELECT c.court_id, 
  court_email_desc, 
  court_email_addr, 
  max(case when court_opening_type_desc = 'Court building open' then court_opening_desc end) Opens,
  max(case when court_opening_type_desc = 'Court building closed' then court_opening_desc end) Closes
FROM court C
JOIN court_email CE 
  ON C.court_id = CE.court_id
JOIN court_opening CO 
  ON C.court_id = CO.court_id
JOIN court_opening_type COT 
  ON CO.court_opening_type_id = COT.court_opening_type_id
WHERE C.court_id = '" + court_id_no + "'
group by c.court_id, court_email_desc, court_email_addr;
```

Edit #2:  My final suggestion if you don't use separate queries would be to implement the `row_number()` and `PIVOT` into a single solution:

```
SELECT court_id, 
  court_email_desc, 
  court_email_addr, 
  max(case when court_opening_type_desc = 'Court building open' and rn=1 then court_opening_desc end) CourtOpens,
  max(case when court_opening_type_desc = 'Court building closed' and rn=1 then court_opening_desc end) CourtCloses
FROM
(
    SELECT c.court_id, 
        court_email_desc, 
        court_email_addr, 
        court_opening_type_desc, 
        court_opening_desc,
        row_number() over(partition by c.court_id, court_opening_type_desc order by court_email_desc) rn
    FROM court C
    JOIN court_email CE 
      ON C.court_id = CE.court_id
    JOIN court_opening CO 
      ON C.court_id = CO.court_id
    JOIN court_opening_type COT 
      ON CO.court_opening_type_id = COT.court_opening_type_id
    WHERE C.court_id = '" + court_id_no + "'
) src
group by court_id, court_email_desc, court_email_addr;
```

The data from the query should display as this:

```
court_id    | court_email_desc          | court_email_addr                      | CourtOpens    | CourtCloses
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1           | Bailiffs                  | bailiffs@bailiffs.email               | 8:30am        | 5:00pm
1           | Public Enquiries Email    | ccmcccustomerenquiries@pubenq.email   |               |
1           | Filing e-documents        | ccmcce-filing@filing.email            |               |
1           | Enquiries                 | enquiries@enquiries.email             |               |
1           | Hearings                  | hearings@hearings.email               |               |
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, however the above doesn't appear to be working. I've run the query straight in SQL Server (I'll deal with C# later) and get much the same output I got the first time aside from the only court email address that outputs now is the first row, and all the others are blank. There is still the record repetition for the 'opening type' and 'opening desc'.

Comment: @DanSolo can you post the desired result of the query?  Obviously I am missing something in your requirement. See my edit with an alternative version which will pivot the open/closed values and you will be left with one row for each of the departments/emails, etc

Comment: Apologies, in hindsight the output wasn't displayed too well and my desired output was obviously missing entirely - you can probably see that your last edit won't have helped much (apologies). In light of my edit above am I barking up the wrong tree entirely with the SQL query and how I'd like it to be output? As I say I'm not sure if 2 queries would be better after all or a different output method in the C#?

Comment: @DanSolo see my edit for a possible solution that would not involve two queries.

Comment: Thanks for all your time and efforts. Whilst your new edit does exactly as you predict, on reflection I'm not sure there is much value to be gained from linking the columns in this way with regards to the final implementation. They are essentially non-dependent datasets (to each other) and should probably have separate queries as such. Thanks for your explanation though, I've definitely learnt something so there has been value in your responses.